# Access JavaScript parent function variable in nested function structure

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-sql

My Code is in phonegap application. While executing a SELECT SQL statement, I am experiencing difficulties to pass the results to parent function's variable. The code is represented below:

```
function db_data(query) {
var result_out;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results) {
        console.log("RETURNED SUCCESSFUL RESULTS"); // SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTING HERE.
        result_out = results.rows;
    }, function (){
        console.log("Error on executing sql");
        result_out = false;
    }); 
});
console.log(result_out); // NOTHING LOGGING HERE.
return result_out;
}
```

This function is to pass common SELECT statements. The function is not returning any thing and the returning object is successfully logged only within the SQL execution function.

Comment: is there somethin in `result.rows`? Have you tried to console.log its value?

Comment: It logs results inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation is asynchronous. The operation inside `db.transaction` may take effect in a later time. By the time you logged the result, it isn't there yet.

If you want to execute something after getting a value for `result_out`, you need to put it inside the callbacks:

```
function db_data(query,callback) {
    var result_out;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results) {
            console.log("RETURNED SUCCESSFUL RESULTS"); // SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTING HERE.
            callback.call(this,results.rows);
        }, function (){
            console.log("Error on executing sql");
            callback.call(this,false);
        }); 
    });
}
```

when using db_data, instead of

```
var result = db_data('your query');
//do something with result
```

do this instead

```
db_data('your query',function(result){
   //do something with result here
   //result will either be a false or the result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the db operations are asynchronous. The value `result_out` is printed before the sql has been executed. You should provide a callback function for `db_data`.

```
function db_data(query, callback) {
  var result_out;
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results) {
      console.log("RETURNED SUCCESSFUL RESULTS"); // SUCCESSFULLY EXECUTING HERE.
      callback(null, result.rows); // <<<<<<<<<<< 
    }, function (){
      callback(new Error('error executing sql')); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }); 
  });
}

db_data('select * ....', function (err, rows) {
    // do something with rows
})
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers are same.